# how to create a hyperlink within a meteor error string

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a section of my meteor error string as a link.

```
if (customer.password) {
    throw new Meteor.Error('server-error_email-in-use', 'Email already in use with a non-guest account, please log in to complete your order');
  }
```

how can i make "log in" a hyperlink to login page?